# How to produce more power than the input power?

Tags: power

How to produce more power than the input power ?

Ex: Input : 24V@90mA required output is 8.2V@400mA

Comment: If you find a way, patent it and you'll have solved the world's energy problems. (Hint: no **real** power converter operates with efficiency higher than 100% - there are always losses.)

Comment: It can't be done.  Period.

Comment: You can't.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy

Comment: Wave your magic wand while intoning *Cunservatus Energius Breakus* and thinking powerful thoughts. If it doesn't work, your magic want is broken or you can't think powerfully enough to do it right.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Provide another power source.
2. Implement a brownout scheme.

The first is obvious and will not be discussed further.

The second involves using a storage element (capacitor or inductor) to store energy while providing little or no actual output power while the storage element charges, and then providing a burst of increased power from the stored energy.

Comment: Option 3: rewrite the laws of physics.  Option 4. hope for a miracle.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a miracle to happen like this. From the law of conservation of energy, it's obviously not possible what you asked. If you need to increase or decrease a voltage, you can use transformers, but you will change the current in exchange and moreover, there is no ideal transformer still invented, so you'll lose energy in small amounts. To boost up voltage, you can use joule thief circuit, but as with a transformer you lose current accordingly.